# Divisibility - what is A+B?

Tags: divisibility

Is there an easy to solve this problem? I can find the answer by using a complicated rule that I don't understand. Even if I try to remember this rule, I probably will forget about it a year later. The rule is "To find out if a number is divisible by 11, add every other digit and call that sum $x$. Add together the remaining digits, and call that sum $y$. Take the positive difference of $x$ and $y$. If the difference is zero or a multiple of eleven, then the original number is a multiple of eleven."

> A and B are non-zero digits for which A468B05 is divisible by 11. What is A+B?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why divisibility is so important in math?

Comment: that's a very loaded question and if you're serious about it I suggest posting it as a separate question or at least searching this site for similar questions.  I think a number theorist can better elaborate but one reason is that divisibility and primes are central ideas in cryptography.

Comment: Divisibility is quite important in Diophantine equations.  You can often restrict the possible solutions to particular residue classes.  The classic divisibility tests  that depend on the base $10$ representation of numbers, not so much.  $73$ is a prime in any base.  The fact that you can test divisibility by $9$ with a trick involving the digits is particular to base $10$ (and some others) so has little mathematical content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=4+8+0$$

$$y=A+6+B+5$$

*Case 1: $x-y=0$*

$$12-11-(A+B)=0$$

**$$A+B=1$$**

This means either $A$ or $B$ is $0$, so it doesn't work.

*Case 2: $x-y=-11$*

$$12-11-(A+B)=-11$$

$$A+B=12$$

$A$ and $B$ can be several combinations of positive nonzero integers that satisfies $A+B=12$, so this is the correct answer.